# Django - readonly_fields renders info put not field

Tags: django-admin

I'm trying to use readonly_fields in my admin but it renders info about the field instead of the value.

My admin.py

```
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('user',)
    list_display = ('user', 'accepted_terms')
    admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileAdmin)
```

It renders

```
{'help_text': u'', 'field': 'user', 'name': 'user', 'label': 'user'}
```

instead of

```
Test user name
```

What am I doing wrong?

Best regards

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are using an older version of the admin templates (some kind of symbolic link or something)?